# PhotoSwipe - how to align one image per column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used PhotoSwipe API from here:
http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html

See "How to build an array of slides from a list of links" => edit on CodePen => Export => Export .zip - can be used to download simple example.

If you use "first / second gallery" layout - them images gets how I want them to - so one image per column. But then when you click on image - it will display only "first gallery" or "second gallery". I would prefer to have one gallery.
If however - you remove following text from html:

```
  </div>

<h2>Second gallery:</h2>

  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
```

Then when resizing web browser - you can get two images per column - I would prefer to have only one image per column. (Depending on image size).

This can be fixed by having all images with same size, but this is not typical situation when you've editing new images.

How can I achieve one gallery and have one image per column ?